# Pyramid page loading animation

Tags: python, pyramid

I use pyramid for an application, and I want to show an hourglass when pyramid loads the new view. Before the view is updated, I have to do some work with a video file, and the page waits for a bunch of seconds before the response. I want to show an animation during that period.

Answer (score 2):

try to use json response and while waiting for the response, you can display your animation 
http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.4-branch/narr/renderers.html